# Which function executes first, done() or always()

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$.getJSON() .done() .always()`, if I use both those handlers to run some code, which of them will execute first? I would assume `done` but I don't have any evidence to back that up.

Comment: Why don't you try it, swap them around and try it again, then report back? **edit** I'm expecting they're invoked in the order they've been chained

Comment: Have a look at the `.always` implementation. I think it's clear then: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/deferred.js#L21

Comment: That was quite unnecessary, @Aerovistae.

Comment: @PaulS. I am a quadriplegic, testing that code using my eyelashes would take me over three hours. Even writing this comment took 15 minutes.